# Django filtering in exclusively

Tags: python, sql, django

The following is Django for filtering if the query is in a list:

```
options = [1,2,3]
result = Example.objects.filter('something__property__in'=options)
```

so here `something` is a `ForeignKey` relation (with multiple relations) to `Example`

I want `result` to be all the `Examples` that have a `something` of 1 AND 2 AND 3. The example code above will be 1 OR 2 OR 3. This would be exclusive!

## examples

the following would **not** be in `result`:

```
examples = Example.objects.all()
things = examples[0].something.all()
for thing in things: print thing.property
#1
#2
#4
#7
```

the following would be in `result`:

```
examples = Example.objects.all()
things = examples[0].something.all()
for thing in things: print thing.property
#1
#2
#8
#9
#3
```

the reason being the second example has everything that is in `options` where the first example has 1 and 2, but not 3!

**Is there a simple way to do this in Django?**

the only thing that I can think to do is just filter with the example I gave above, get all `properties` in a list. And compare the list with `options` in the following python function:

```
def exclusive_in(list1,list2):
    count = 0
    for i in list1:
        if i in list2:
            count += 1
    if count == len(list2):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

I feel like Django could do this in its queries to the database, which would be much more efficient. Any ideas?

## note:

this must work for an arbitrary number of items in `options`, it could be any number greater than 2, even 10 or 100 (although 100 is not likely, it is still possible)

also note that `options` will be populated by strings

Answer (score 3):

The only way I am aware of is to pass in query some custom condition with `extra` method.

Django [won't allow you](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10724) to pass this condition with `tables` param, so it has to be in `where`. See following example with `django.contrib.auth models` (Admin group in the example has all the permissions):

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth import models
>>> permissions_id = [1,2]
>>> where = """(select count(1)
...               from auth_group_permissions gp
...              where gp.permission_id in ({})
...                and gp.group_id = auth_group.id) = {}"""    
>>> where = where.format(','.join(map(str, permissions_id)), 
...                      str(len(permissions_id )))
>>> models.Group.objects.extra(where=[where]).all()
[<Group: Admin>]
>>> print models.Group.objects.extra(where=[where]).all().query
SELECT `auth_group`.`id`, `auth_group`.`name` 
  FROM `auth_group` WHERE (select count(1)
                      from auth_group_permissions gp
                     where gp.permission_id in (1,2)
                       and gp.group_id = auth_group.id) = 2
```

Comment: i'm not 100% sure if this is exclusive for an arbitrary number of items in the `options` list. can you give me a sample output?

Comment: @Ryan, what do you mean by exclusive? This orm request, as shown in SQL (bottom), returns all groups that have related permissions whith ids 1 and 2. If wont forget, will add some db data dump for explanation a bit later. You can change result to any list of pemissions_id due to `join` and `len` usage. What **is** tricky, but implementable, is extra where generation for arbitrary model, you have to infer correct table and field names.

Comment: You understood my meaning of exclusive: it must contain all items that are in `options` or in your case, `permissions_id`. My issue here is that, as you just pointed out, this will only work if you know exactly what the list is beforehand. I need it to be for an arbitrary number of options where none of the options are known. This is for an API.

Comment: @RyanSaxe I'm again confused, as you know your options list (list2) in your example. `list2` has the same meaning as `permissions_id` in my code, once you know them, format where and run `extra` to get result.

Comment: I know that, and that is exactly my point, I will not know them because this is for an API! People need to be able to use this kind of exclusive search with the API, so I cannot hard-code `where` since the items in `list2` are unknown as well as how many items there are!

Comment: @RyanSaxe Still don't get your concerns. You have `where` as template, once your end user knows options_ids, he passes them to a function (f.ex. a custom manager method) and function formats where condtion, executes extra comand and voila, you get your result.

Comment: okay that makes sense, could you please explain your `where` strng? I am not too familiar with it right now. specifically how it would be possible to make it arbitrary because that statement only works with 2 inputs...I understand how it formats, but the first instance of the string is specific to each individual case anyways